# Unable to install postgresql with Homebrew in Yosemite

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew, osx-yosemite

I'm trying to install postgresql via homebrew on Yosemite and I'm getting the following error:

```
checking for libperl... no
configure: error: libperl library is required for Perl
```

I've tried to see about manually installing libperl but I haven't had any success. I have command line tools and xcode installed. Also brew doctor says everything is fine. Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: This was broken in the version of Yosemite I was using. It is fixed now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `brew install postgresql --no-perl` as temporary solution.

Check the status of other formulas [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/29988)